# What is the fastest way to get GameObject reference?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

Let's say my script is defined as given below.

```cs
public GameObject _GameObject;

private void Start()
{
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    _GameObject = gameObject;
}
```

Would this execute faster?

```cs
public void SetActive(bool value)
{
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S60FB.jpg
    gameObject.SetActive(value);
}
```

Or this?

```cs
public void SetActive(bool value)
{
    _GameObject.SetActive(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Unity 4.x and below, the cache method would be significantly faster. In those versions, MonoBehaviour.transform and MonoBehaviour.gameObject were not actually fields; rather, "under the hood" they behaved like properties with an attached accessor.

Thus accessing the gameObject property would make a method call to Component.get_gameobject() via the accessor. Of course, a method call naturally imposes more overhead than a simple memory access. (Transform was worse; apparently the accessor actually invoked the GetComponent method to return the value!)

This is why you will often see veteran Unity developers caching these values.

I have it on good authority that this process has been streamlined in Unity 5 for better performance; using the built-in properties will still create a very small amount of overhead but it is reportedly insignificant.

Source: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/23/unity5-api-changes-automatic-script-updating/

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that caching the variable is faster than using the `gameObject` variable from the [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) class and a simple test proved that to be true. That's because caching it will give you the reference rather than using `gameObject` which uses the `get` accessor to return the reference. Not sure if getting the reference requires a native function call but that's a possibility.  Using `get` accessor  is slower than direct reference access.

Let's say you have 1 million scripts calling `gameObject.activeSelf` or through the cached version `_GameObject.activeSelf`.

Test Result:

> gameObject: `54` ms
>
> Cached _GameObject: `30` ms

Software/Hardware tested on:

- Unity 5.6.0f3
- Windows 10 Pro
- MacBookPro11,4
- 16 GB RAM

Does it matter?

In a normal app, maybe not. In a game, yes. Removing `24ms` from  a game is a good improvement depending on the kind of Game.

Test script:

```
public GameObject _GameObject;

void Start()
{
    Application.runInBackground = true;

    int iterations = 1000000;

    //TEST 1
    Stopwatch stopwatch1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        bool active = gameObject.activeSelf;
    }
    stopwatch1.Stop();

    //TEST 2
    Stopwatch stopwatch2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        bool active = _GameObject.activeSelf;
    }
    stopwatch2.Stop();
    //SHOW RESULT
    WriteLog(String.Format("gameObject: {0}", stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds));
    WriteLog(String.Format("Cached _GameObject: {0}", stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds));
}

void WriteLog(string log)
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(log);
}
```